# Attempting to use BrowserMobProxy with Selenium, getting permission denied error

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, browsermob

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "facebook_scraper.py", line 185, in <module>
fb_scraper()
File "facebook_scraper.py", line 36, in fb_scraper
server.start()
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/browsermobproxy/server.py", line 56, in start
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I am following instructions from this [page](https://browsermob-proxy-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Check that the user running the Python script has the permission to run the browsermob proxy batch file, that should be a .bat file found in `path/to/browsermob-proxy`

```
server = Server("path/to/browsermob-proxy")
```